# How many times Vegeta has surpassed Goku in power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

We know of a few times Vegeta was stronger than Goku.

- Before arriving to Earth, prior Goku learnt kaioken (This shouldn't count as surpassing, since he started being stronger)
- The first time he went out of the time chamber.
- The time Beerus slapped Bulma.

But there were other times, I'm sure, and there are some dubious ones, like the first time he became super saiyan, if I recall correctly, it was Piccolo who stated Vegeta might have surpassed Goku.

Therefore my question is,

How many times Vegeta has surpassed Goku in power?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vegeta has surpassed Goku on a few occasions! Only for a short duration though. Here is a list of all the times Vegeta surpassed Goku.

**Android Saga(When Vegeta First turns SSJ)**: It was mentioned by Picollo when Vegeta turned SSJ that he was notably stronger than Goku. This was the same time Goku was infected with the heart virus.

**Cell Games(Post HTC)**: Once Vegeta and Future Trunks came out of the HTC just before Goku went in with Gohan, Vegeta was obviously stronger than Goku then.

**Battle of Gods(vs Beerus)**: This is notably the highest margin by which Vegeta has surpassed Goku. Base Vegeta was definitely as stronger or weaker than Base Goku at this time. The SSJ2 transformation is a 100 times multiplier while the SSJ3 is a 400 times multiplier. Vegeta surpassing the same with his rage boost, made him a lot stronger than SSJ3 Goku.

**6 Months of training with Whis**: We do not know this to a certainty, however, it was stated by Goku once he went to Beerus's world to train with Whis that Vegeta might be as strong or possibly even stronger than him.

**Rematch against Goku Black(Note: Kaioken is not considered here because it is a special technique)**: While Goku was mastering the mafuba, Vegeta trained in the HTC and surpassed Goku. Vegeta overwhelmed Black until he converted his ki blade to a scythe.(Black was slower, yet his power had surpassed Vegeta's again). Also, note that this might not be very accurate because we see Goku pushing back a holy wrath from  Merged Zamasu and fighting him on his own while Future Trunks(SSJ Rage)+SSJB Vegeta together struggled to push back a beam attack from Merged Zamasu. My only explanation for the same is that Goku got a Zenkai Boost which made him as strong as Vegeta was by the end of this arc.

Comment: I fear tht it becomes difficult to really say if it is not explicitely stated by the characters as Goku most of the times does NOT fight at full strength.......because of his pride/arrogance and then gets his A. kicked (see battle vs. golden freezer and the warning he got about this before that from whis).

Comment: Well to be fair whatever I said is accurate. With regard to freiza, Freiza was stronger than SSJB Goku. Goku only won because of Freiza's stamina drain. The first 3 times were stated explicitly. The last time, we obviously see Goku fighting at full strength. We even see him get a rage boost when Zamasu talks about killing Chichi and Goten. Also, Goku lost against the stronger level of Black which Vegeta came back and defeated.

Answer (score 0):

All the above plus when vegeta healed up after his fight with Racoom is suspect. Again short lived as goku came back from his near death experience stronger.

Comment: Hi. Please provide answers that can stand on its own and do not require clarification from the asker. 'All of the the above' can refer to a lot of things. Also, inclusion of relevant sources (episodes, chapters, etc) is a requirement for every answer here.

Comment: This is a good point actually. Goku had a power level of 90,000 and Vegeta post-Recoome had a power level of 250,000. Although, Goku did have Kaioken at the time.